# Python string formatting

Tags: python

I came here to ask a simple, very beginner question regarding python.

I just started learning, using http://www.learnpython.org

The problem is, on the `string formatting` section, it doesn't really explain how can I do the exercise in the code window.

The general way this site teaches the language is like: It shows the commands/functions, gives some examples, and then it has an exercise in order to continue.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What did you try? What was the results?

Comment: If you have a specific question about string formatting in python, please do go ahead and post it! But the SO community can't improve the content of an external programming website.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but I don't understand how can I complete the exercise.

Comment: Can you at least point which exercise it is?

Comment: I already pointed out, it's in the string formatting section.

Comment: I would complete the exercise by re-reading the text before the exercise until I understood how it works, and then trying to write something that matches my understanding. If I failed, then I would post a question showing what I tried, what actual result I got and what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on [diveintopython.net](http://www.diveintopython.net/), it's a really good book. The part on string formatting should get obvious.

Basically, it is used to handle easy formatting, such as csv.

```
name = 'foo'
age = 42
print "Hi %s, you are %d years old\n" % (name, age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello %s %s. Your current balance is %d$"

print format_string % data
```

?